# Is there a term for if someone uses their own words on idioms consciously?

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, terminology

For example, instead of "barking up the wrong tree", someone uses "pulling out the wrong plant". Consciously or not, is there a term for saying idioms in your own words?

Comment: @MattЭллен our communication has been deleted on the subject of receiving a -1 score on a topic that I neither responded to, nor commented on.  I have a screen capture of this score, and request an explanation: 
achievements
utc time 18:16
Today +12
 "...   +10
    What does "she was as generous in sharing her death as she was in sharing her life" mean?
    –1
    Is there a term for if someone uses their own words on idioms consciously?
    You've earned the "Custodian" badge..."

Answer (score 1):

Such off-center words and phrases are called *malapropisms*, and the speaker is called a ***malapropist***.

mal·a·prop·ism noun \ˈma-lə-ˌprä-ˌpi-zəm\
: an amusing error that occurs when a person mistakenly uses a word that sounds like another word but that has a very different meaning

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malapropism

Comment: I don't believe I would call someone who *consciously* changes the words in an idiom a malapropist. (I know the OP said "consciously or not" in the question, but the question title says consciously.)

Answer (score 0):

These can be called **Ziva-isms**, named after the character Ziva David from NCIS. [Here's a long list of some of hers.](http://ncis.wikia.com/wiki/Ziva-Isms)

Comment: + 1 - http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Ziva-ism